# DataFrame and Python don't find the columns' names of a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I use DataFrame in Python in order to manipulate CSV files. So I use things like df['column_name'].

but df doesn't seem to find the column in the file (writes a "KeyError"), even if there really is that column, and even if I checked it back to see if there was a mistake in the letters.
So if I want my program to work, and my CSV file to be readen by df and python, I need to manually change the name of the column that I want to manipulate before everything.
To explain the situation, the files I manipulate are not from me, they're pregenerated, and so it looks like python doesn't want to read it if I don't change the name of the column, because everything works after changing it.
I hope you have understood and you'll be able to help me !

Comment: Can you provide an example of the file you're reading in and the code you're using to do so?

Comment: Make a [mcve] that exhibits the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the 'column_name' in file and code, both are in capital or both are in small letters? sometimes it gives error when one is in capital but another one is in small letters.

Comment: Yes, I know this is important, so i make it so everything is ok with names and variables, I  even do a copy/paste directly from the file to check that, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked for white spaces? like tabs or line breaks.

EDIT:

Now that you know the problem is a linebreak and that perhaps other columns on the data frame have the same problem, you can clean them like this

before:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A',1],
                   ['B',2],
                   ['C',3],
                   ['D',4],
                   ['E',5]], columns=['column 1 \n',' \n column2 \n'])
output:
  column 1 \n   \n column2 \n
0   A                1
1   B                2
2   C                3
3   D                4
4   E                5
```

After:

```
#cleaning the column names

new_columns = [i.strip() for i in df.columns]

df.columns = new_columns

    column 1    column2
0     A           1
1     B           2
2     C           3
3     D           4
4     E           5
```

Comment: I'm going to check those things, I will tell you the updates

Comment: hope the update was useful

Comment: Do I have to change something, or just copy/paste it in the program ? Because after copy/pasting it, nothing has changed, it still doesn't work. (also, sorry for the waiting, I didn't have time since now)

Answer (score 0):

ok, I figured the thing out but I don't know how to deal with it:
I get that, from the file I want to manipulate, if I copy the column named "Time":

```
(Time
)
```

I added brackets just to show that it goes to the line right after, so it seems to be a problem from the original file, with the name of the column having a "enter" literaly in itself.
So it makes that for example in a code:

```
time = df['Time
']
```

It prevents the code from working.
I don't have any idea about how to deal with it, and I don't think I can fix it by fixing the column's name in the file because it is pregenerated.

Comment: `time = df['Time\n']` may work if there is a single newline in the column name.

Comment: I just tried it, it doesn't work, so I think it's not a single newline.

Comment: What does `df.columns` return?  It should show *exactly* what the column names are, e.g.  `Index(['Time\r\n', 'Col2\n', 'Col3  \r  ', 'Col4  \n  '], dtype='object')`

Comment: It returns : ```Index(['No.;Time;Comment;Scramble;Date;P.1'], dtype='object')```, (the column we're looking for is the second one "Time"), also, I just tested if the same thing happens to the other columns, and it actually happens.

Comment: So that is one long column name.  The dataframe wasn't loaded correctly.  Need something like `pd.read_csv(filename,sep=';')` to split on semicolons.

Comment: Ok, I added ```pd.read_csv(filename,sep=';')```, everything is working now, thank you for your help !